# Recursive query execute on server but not in local

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, recursion

This is my set up: I'm using SQL server on my Windows Pc and I have a server with SQL Server over Windows Server...

The point here is that I need to develop a procedure to truncate all the table in my DB at any given time... To do that on my large DB (still in developing and growing) I need a query that can find all the foreign key dependency hierarchy so that I can truncate all the table in the list given by the query... I find that **recursive** query online but the point is that **the query execute on the server but not on localhost...** The query need a recursion level of 5 (max) but even if I specify it in the query (**option (maxrecursion 100)**) it doesn't execute locally...

This is the query:

```
WITH dependencies -- Get object with FK dependencies
AS (
    SELECT FK.TABLE_NAME AS Obj
        , PK.TABLE_NAME AS Depends
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
        ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
        ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    ), 
no_dependencies -- The first level are objects with no dependencies 
AS (
    SELECT 
        name AS Obj
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT obj FROM dependencies) --we remove objects with dependencies from first CTE
    AND type = 'U' -- Just tables
    ), 
recursiv -- recursive CTE to get dependencies
AS (
    SELECT Obj AS [Table]
        , CAST('' AS VARCHAR(max)) AS DependsON
        , 0 AS LVL -- Level 0 indicate tables with no dependencies
    FROM no_dependencies
 
    UNION ALL
 
    SELECT d.Obj AS [Table]
        , CAST(IIF(LVL > 0, r.DependsON + ' > ', '') + d.Depends AS VARCHAR(max)) -- visually reflects hierarchy
        , R.lvl + 1 AS LVL
    FROM dependencies d
    INNER JOIN recursiv r
        ON d.Depends = r.[Table]
    )
-- The final result, with some extra fields for more information
SELECT DISTINCT SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id) AS [TableSchema]
    , R.[Table]
    , R.DependsON
    , R.LVL
FROM recursiv R
INNER JOIN sys.objects O
    ON R.[Table] = O.name
ORDER BY R.LVL
    , R.[Table]

option (maxrecursion 100);
```

Comment: Rather than deleting everything, it might be easier to create all the objects from your project/source control.

Comment: @Larnu can you explain yourself better

Comment: Use your database project/source control to *create* the database fresh, which means it will come with no data.

Comment: @Larnu no, I can't because the DB is  mega-gigantic and there are some system table that I can't truncate

Comment: @Larnu the Db is for a big application and I need a reset button that truncate only certain table name that I retrive from a list via code, I use .NET MVC for my app... I need an algorithm that does this job even if it is a code algo and not sql

Comment: If it's only one table, why do you need all the above logic then..?

Comment: @Larnu No sorry, I mispell on the message... The tables to delete will be hundreds and hundreds and I can't do it manually finiding the dependency via a sql schema... I need an algo that given a list of hundreds of table can truncate them respection the foreign key constraints

Comment: could you please clarify the meaning of"does not execute locally". Query produces incorrect results or error or something else?

Comment: @Sergey the query continue to load but does not give a result, or if I don't specify option (maxrecursion 100) it gives an error

Comment: What does "mega-gigantic" mean?  That is a very relative term.  If the suggestion @larnu  makes about source control is not workable then conceivably you could employ a backup / restore procedure and save yourself this hassle.  I would imagine there is at least a level of compression implemented.

Comment: @squillman 345 tabels... I need a procedure or some algo that can find a correct list to truncate certain tables (250/345) at any given time respecting the foreign key constraint

Comment: 345 tables doesn't give any indication of size of the database.  I would actually call that relatively small, schema-wise.  You can make 1000 tables with 1 INT field and the db will be only a handful of KB.  What we're trying to offer you is alternate, easier methods for getting to your end goal.  Often times what someone perceives they need is not the only solution and a different method ends up working better.  If your database does not take a lot of storage it could very well be easier to just back it up and restore it to your PC instead of writing some complex sync process.

Comment: @squillman Ok, but as I said 50 of the totale number of tables cannot be truncate because of their essential data for the application...Furthermore the application is still growing and the Db grow as well...My job is to create  a button that truncate all the tables signed as resettable and I can't create a backup manually because it will not be a solution for the long term... Because the Db will change in the future and I will have to change the backup as well...

Comment: So are you needing to truncate hundreds of tables, but you will also have hundreds of tables that don't need to be affected?

Comment: @squillman the db have some tables with 50-100 fields it is an industrial program not a simple app done by a teen

Comment: @Larnu exaclty...

Comment: I'm not implying that it's some "simple app done by a teen"...   50-100 fields also doesn't give a good indication of _storage size_.  I think you've missed the point of what I was saying, but whatever.

Comment: @squillman I get the point but your solution cannot be applied... The db is growing and I can't manually create a backup that suits my need everytime ...

Comment: Why not disable all the foreign key constraints, truncate the tables you need to truncate and enable the foreign keys again?

Comment: _I can't manually create a backup that suits my need everytime_ well, if the data's that important then you shouldn't be creating manual backups at all - they should be fully automated and getting automatically restored somewhere else to verify successful backups.

Comment: @Wouter ok, but how can I re-enable the foreign key?

Comment: It seems like you have a cycle of foreign key constraints somewhere in your local database, e.g.: a parent-child hierarchy table.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, actually you need to drop the foreign keys first, otherwise you cannot TRUNCATE the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the reason about why this is happening to you...
What I can suggest is to follow these steps to achieve your goal:

1. Disable all your foreign key constraints with this: `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"`
2. Then perform all the delete you want
3. Enable all your foreign key constraints with this: `exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?'", @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"`

You may argue that this is a risky cheat but let me explain:
You probabily have a pool of tables seen by the users and some **system setting** tables. These two groups of tables will not be linked together (if not even your recurive query will say to you that is impossible to delete a "user table" if you don't delete a **system setting** table).
So you can trust my logic and truncate all the "user table" with your eyes closed

Answer (score 2):

Why not keeping a periodic backup of your database with the table you want to truncate empty and load this backup everytime you want a fresh installation of your app